# Word VSTO : finding all the Ranges that use a specific font

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm working on an add-in that can detect source code snippets inserted in a Word document. This works by checking the font : for example, code pasted in Word from Visual Studio 2017 uses the Consolas font. I've had quick success with this, when it comes to finding paragraphs. Here's what that code looks like :

```
var Snippets = from Word.Paragraph p in PageContent.Paragraphs
               where p.Range.Font.Name == "Consolas"
               select p;
```

But I would like instead to return whole Ranges. Code pasted from VS2017 is basically one paragraph per line of code, so this approach only gives me individual lines. Typically, a document could contain several snippets, each with several lines of code, separated by text.

Also, I may have small bits of code inserted in a normal phrase, like a method name, for example.

Is there a simple way to get all the Ranges in a Range that use a specific font ?

Comment: As far as I know, there' s no way to return a Range larger than a paragraph. My first thought was Word's "Find" functionality, but each "found" is no larger than a paragraph. What's the mechanism for transferring the code snippets from VS into Word? Perhaps that could be combined with something to more quickly identify "blocks" such as content controls or bookmarks...

Comment: Hello Cindy, the code is simply copy-pasted in a Word document from VS, for example when I want to add a code example to a document. Since I've asked the question, I've come up with a complex but fast method to find consecutive paragraphs and/or words that use a certain font. I've also looked at the word document object model for collections that might be useful, but I haven't found any, so I guess my method will have to do.